# Join to Date hierarchy table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I’m looking someways to join both these query into a single table.

This is the query for my Week, month and year number hierarchy.

SQL query #1:

```
DECLARE @Year AS INT,
        @FirstDateOfYear DATETIME,
        @LastDateOfYear DATETIME

-- You can change @year to any year you desire
SELECT @year = 2018
SELECT @FirstDateOfYear = DATEADD(yyyy, @Year - 1900, 0)
SELECT @LastDateOfYear = DATEADD(yyyy, @Year - 1900 + 1, 0)

-- Creating Query to Prepare Year Data
;WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT 
        1 AS DayID,
        @FirstDateOfYear AS FromDate,
        DATENAME(dw, @FirstDateOfYear) AS Dayname

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        cte.DayID + 1 AS DayID,
        DATEADD(d, 1 ,cte.FromDate),
        DATENAME(dw, DATEADD(d, 1 ,cte.FromDate)) AS Dayname
    FROM 
        cte
    WHERE 
        DATEADD(d,1,cte.FromDate) < @LastDateOfYear
)
SELECT 
    FromDate AS WeekEnd, 
    Dayname, 
    WeekofYr = DATEPART(WEEK, FromDate), 
    MonthofYr = DATEPART(MONTH, FromDate), 
    YearofYR = DATEPART(YY, FromDate)
--into #temp
FROM 
    CTE
WHERE 
    DayName LIKE 'Saturday' 
    OPTION (MaxRecursion 370)
```

Here is another piece of query that’ gives a different data. I wanted to join the results of this to my SQL query 1 results

SQL query #2:

```
select 
    a.ClaimNum,
    featureName, case when Subro = 1 and PD + BI +SIU + LITIGATION = 0 THEN 1 else 0 end as subro_only, PD,BI,Subro,SIU,Litigation, 
    c.FeatureStatus
from 
    (select
         f.ClaimNum,                            
         sum(case when rtrim([FeatureName]) = 'Prop'   then 1  else 0 end ) as  'PD', 
         sum(case when ( rtrim([FeatureName]) = 'CL-BI'   or rtrim([FeatureName]) = 'CLMT.MED' )   then 1  else 0 end )as  'BI',
         sum(case when rtrim([FeatureName]) = 'CL-Subro'   then 1  else 0 end) as  'Subro',
         sum(case when rtrim([FeatureName]) = 'CL-SI'   then 1  else 0 end )as  'SIU',
         sum(case when rtrim([FeatureName]) = 'CL-Litigation'    then 1  else 0 end) as  'Litigation',
         sum(case when rtrim([FeatureName]) = 'Claim'    then 1  else 0 end) as  'Claim'
     from
         [dbo].[Snapshot]  F                                                                                                                                   
     where
         RowIsCurrent = 'Y'
         and isnull(FeatureStatus,'') not in ('Closed','Cancelled','Abandoned','') 
     group by ClaimNum) a   
inner join 
    [dbo].[Snapshot] C on c.ClaimNum = a.ClaimNum and c.FeatureName = 'Claim'  
                       and isnull(c.FeatureStatus, '') not in ('Closed', 'Cancelled', 'Abandoned', '')
```

Sample data for SQL query 2

```
  ClaimNum    ModifiedDate     featureName  subro_    PD    BI  Subro   SIU Litigation  FeatureStatus
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    2062682     12/25/2015          Claim       1       0   0   1       0       0       Open
    2278808     2/11/2018           Claim       0       0   0   0       0       0       Open
    2278678     2/11/2018           Claim       0       0   0   0       0       0       Open
    2269016     2/11/2018           Claim       1       0   0   1       0       0       Open
    2267544     1/2/2018            Claim       0       0   0   0       0       0       Open
    2268099     1/3/2018            Claim       0       0   0   0       0       0       Open
    2038182     9/4/2015            Claim       0       0   0   0       0       0       Open
    2330116     6/5/2018            Claim       0       0   0   0       0       0       Open
    2330084     6/5/2018            Claim       0       0   0   0       0       0       Open
    2329982     6/5/2018            Claim       0       0   0   0       0       0       Open
    2330218     6/5/2018            Claim       0       0   0   0       0       0       Open
    2330165     6/5/2018            Claim       0       0   0   0       0       0       Open
    2330399     6/5/2018            Claim       0       0   0   0       1       0       Suspended - SIU
```

I wanted to join the results of two querys into single table by using modified date. For instance if **modified date is June 5th, 2018** then it should be in the row whose weekend date is 06/09/2018.

Also, I wanted the results only for the current calendar year. I want my final table to have all columns of first query and all columns of 2nd query

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the results of the first query?   What would the result of the join look like, using the same sample data?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to play with performance but you basically need to LEFT JOIN all your data against your calendar. Since you want all of the data you need to get the MIN(Saturday) that is GREATER than each of the data records. You could have done the last part in the AlignedSaturdays' select, however,  I split it up for readability and rejoined on the Saturday table.

```
;WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT 
        1 AS DayID,
        @FirstDateOfYear AS FromDate,
        DATENAME(dw, @FirstDateOfYear) AS Dayname

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        cte.DayID + 1 AS DayID,
        DATEADD(d, 1 ,cte.FromDate),
        DATENAME(dw, DATEADD(d, 1 ,cte.FromDate)) AS Dayname
    FROM 
        cte
    WHERE 
        DATEADD(d,1,cte.FromDate) < @LastDateOfYear
)
,Saturdays AS
(
    SELECT 
        FromDate AS WeekEnd, 
        Dayname, 
        WeekofYr = DATEPART(WEEK, FromDate), 
        MonthofYr = DATEPART(MONTH, FromDate), 
        YearofYR = DATEPART(YY, FromDate)
    --into #temp
    FROM 
        CTE
    WHERE 
        DayName LIKE 'Saturday' 
)  
,AllData AS
(
    select 
        a.ClaimNum,
        c.ModifiedDate     
        featureName, case when Subro = 1 and PD + BI +SIU + LITIGATION = 0 THEN 1 else 0 end as subro_only, PD,BI,Subro,SIU,Litigation, 
        c.FeatureStatus
    from 
        (select
             f.ClaimNum,                            
             sum(case when rtrim([FeatureName]) = 'Prop'   then 1  else 0 end ) as  'PD', 
             sum(case when ( rtrim([FeatureName]) = 'CL-BI'   or rtrim([FeatureName]) = 'CLMT.MED' )   then 1  else 0 end )as  'BI',
             sum(case when rtrim([FeatureName]) = 'CL-Subro'   then 1  else 0 end) as  'Subro',
             sum(case when rtrim([FeatureName]) = 'CL-SI'   then 1  else 0 end )as  'SIU',
             sum(case when rtrim([FeatureName]) = 'CL-Litigation'    then 1  else 0 end) as  'Litigation',
             sum(case when rtrim([FeatureName]) = 'Claim'    then 1  else 0 end) as  'Claim'
         from
             [dbo].[Snapshot]  F                                                                                                                                   
         where
             RowIsCurrent = 'Y'
             and isnull(FeatureStatus,'') not in ('Closed','Cancelled','Abandoned','') 
         group by ClaimNum) a   
    inner join 
        [dbo].[Snapshot] C on c.ClaimNum = a.ClaimNum and c.FeatureName = 'Claim'  
                           and isnull(c.FeatureStatus, '') not in ('Closed', 'Cancelled', 'Abandoned', '')
)
,AlignedSaturdays AS
(
    SELECT 
        ClaimNum,
        featureName,
        FeatureStatus,
        ModifiedDate,
        NextSaturday = MAX(Saturdays.FromDate),
    FROM
        Saturdays
        LEFT OUTER JOIN AllData ON AllData.ModifiedDate < Saturdays.FromDate
    GROUP BY
        ClaimNum,
        featureName,
        FeatureStatus,
        ModifiedDate
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    AlignedSaturdays
    INNER JOIN Saturdays ON Saturdays.FromDate = AlignedSaturdays.NextSaturday
 OPTION (MaxRecursion 370)
```